# How I can mux multiple TS streams(from IPTV) in real-time for DVBT?

Tags: mpeg, mux

I tried with FFmpeg for mux 
But, FFmpeg performance is not good for real-time mode.
So, I want to know the method/theory of mux.

[image: screen]

```
ffmpeg.exe -y                                   \
  -i http://example.net:8000/content/xxx        \
  -i http://example.net:8000/content/yyy        \
  -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 1:1           \
  -program program_num=1:st=0:st=1              \
  -program program_num=2:st=2:st=3 -c copy -f mpegts -muxrate 18095940 out5.ts
```

I checked the FFmpeg source code, the FFmpeg decode the input stream. And mux to new `TS` stream, but, I want to mux with original IPTV's `TS` packet without decode.

Comment: Ffmpeg performance should be fine for real-time. What command were you running?

Comment: I added my ffmpeg command, with above command, I cannot get `1.0x` speed, and the `out.TS` is not enough for realtime broadcast to DVBT.